# escape sequence \K for regular expression in boost library

Tags: boost, boost-regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I need to replace a look-behind expression with \K in boost (version 1.54) because of its limitation but it does not work. How can I do it or what is the problem? Is there any other way to convert this expression with lookahead?

"(?<=foo.*) bar"  => "foo.*\K bar"   ???

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a late answer here...

According to the [Boost.Regex 1.54 Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html), use of Perl's \K is possible, and I have just confirmed it via testing in Sublime Text 3, which uses Boost.Regex for its regex searching engine. Furthermore, I see no obvious syntactical error with either of the forms you posted. The only thing I can think of is that you're using the regex inside a string literal, and haven't escaped the \. If that's the case, the correct regex for your example would be:

```
foo.*\\K bar
```

If that's not the case, one workaround (that obviously has performance implications) is to reverse the string, and then use a variable-width look-ahead.
The modified regex for your example would then be:

```
rab (?=.*oof)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that Boost lookbehind [pattern must be of fixed length](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.lookbehind).

Your expression contains a repeat `.*` which makes it variable length.